# When Marathon run all docker apps on same host the docker service stop

Tags: docker, centos6, marathon

I'm using Marathon and Mesos to deploy/run some docker services (mongodb, elasticsearch, etc.) all with constraint to run on same node.

When I submit one by one with some time interval the result was successful but when I post all apps at once the docker services stop immediately after some pull...I suppose that the problem is around overhead of docker pull but I can't found any about it.

**The node environment**:

- Marathon: 0.13.0
- Mesos:    0.26.0
- Docker:   1.7.1 storage: aufs
- OS:       CentOS 6.7 kernel: 3.19.3 with aufs support

Comment: Please provide relevant parts of the Mesos and Marathon logs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend tweaking `--max_tasks_per_offer`. In Marathon `0.13.0` it was set to `100` by default. I would recommend setting it to a number in single digits. Try with `5`.

How many apps are you launching at once ?

Comment: ok, but do you know any issue associated with docker about it? because I think that the main problem is with docker pull.

Comment: I'm not sure or any particular docker issues. Can't say much without Mesos/Marathon logs. You mentioned you were launching a lot of apps at once and I have seen problems in the past if you try to launch more apps than your Agent(slave) node can handle at once.

Comment: Well my real scenario is deploying 10 docker apps on same node.